# Consume Flask video streaming with ffmpeg

Tags: python-3.x, flask, ffmpeg, video-streaming, flask-restful

I've created a python Flask video file streamer resource that works well when getting the file in a web browser but is not working when using ffmpeg.
The flask resource is:

```
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

class Mp4(Resource):
    def get(self,grtv,data,canal,arquivo):

        path = os.path.abspath('../mp4/' + str(canal) + '/' + str(data) + '/' + str(arquivo))

        print(path)
        def generate():
            with open(path, "rb") as f:
                chunk = f.read(1024)
                while chunk:
                    yield chunk
                    chunk = f.read(1024)

        try:
            t = os.stat(path)
            size = str(t.st_size)
            return Response(generate(),mimetype='video/mp4',headers={"Content-Type":"video/mp4","Content-Disposition":"inline","Content-Transfer-Enconding":"binary","Content-Length":size})
        except Exception as e:
            result = {'result': e}
            return result
```

The ffmpeg command is:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel debug -i <url> out_teste4.mp4
```

where url is de address of the streaming video.

The ffmpeg most important output is:

[ffmpeg output screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve1Mk.png)

[ffmpeg output screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMAW5.png)

I've already tried increasing 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options.

ffmpeg version: 3.4.2-1~16.04.york0.2.

python version: 3.5.2.

Does anyone can help me to get the video files with ffmpeg? Suggestions can be both on changing the API or the ffmpeg command.

Thank you all!